# How can I pass parameters Latitude and Longitude in method doInBackground?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, reverse-geocoding

I tried to use reverse geocoding with AsyncTask but but the parameters of latitude and longitude that passes through the method doInBackground() are not happening correctly. any idea?

```
public class SitesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StackSite> { 
    public static Double lat;
    public static Double lng;

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ...
        lat = -1.80; 
        lng = -80.20;
    ...
    }
    public void start(){
        new GetAddressTask(mContext).execute(lat, lng);  
    }

    public static class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, String> {
        //mContext            

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Double... params) {
            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());          
            List<Address> list = null;
            String city = "";
            double latitude = params[0];
            double longitude = params[1];           
            try {
                list = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);             
            } catch (IOException e) {               
                e.printStackTrace();                
            }               
            if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                Address address = list.get(0);
                city = String.format("%s, %s", address.getAdminArea(), address.getCountryName());                             
            }
            return city;            
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String city) {         
            tituloTxt.setText(city);
        }
    }
}
```

error:

```
11-21 15:10:24.409: E/Trace(24502): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Basic Java. Are you familiar with fields, setters and getters?

Comment: RTFM. It's right there:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: The error you provided is useless. Where is stack trace? Some useful information? You don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after so only had to do this to pass the coordinates. First add coordinate to constructor LatLng(double latitude, double longitude) and pass the parameters.

```
    lat = -1.80; 
    lng = -80.20;
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    new GetAddressTask(mContext).execute(lat, lng);
```

Then inside the doInbackground method get parameters.

```
public static class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, String> {
    //mContext            

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());          
        List<Address> list = null;
        String city = "";
        LatLng loc = params[0]; //Get all parameters: latitude and longitude         
        try {
          list = gc.getFromLocation(loc.latitude, loc.longitude, 1); //get specific parameters                
        } catch (IOException e) {           
           e.printStackTrace();              
        }
        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
          Address address = list.get(0);
          city = String.format("%s, %s", address.getAdminArea(), address.getCountryName());
          return city;
       }else{
          return "City no found";
       }                
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String city) {         
        tituloTxt.setText(city);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add two variables to your class and set them when you create async task, then use them in method. Simple.

```
public class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        Context mContext;
        float lat,lin;

        public void setLat(int lat){...}

       //rest of class
```

of course you can make everything static (fields and setters).

Edit.

If you are calling execute with some parameters, remember that your values have to be set before calling execute.

Comment: or task.execute(lat, lng);

Comment: I try to pass the coordinates and execute the AsyncTask but I have a error. I updated above.

Answer (score -1):

before calling execute method, u can just create  a constructor ,in which you can initialize your class data members which can be further used in  doInBackground(..).